# How can I read json from ajax POST in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, ajax

I want to create a form with contenteditable div, where a user types in a string. On button click the form is submitted and check() function is called. Ajax POST request is sent, which may contain the submitted string (now it's just "hello" for simplicity). In PHP, I should be able to get that string ("hello") and echo it for example, but `json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"))` returns empty. Please help :(

My HTML form in index.view.php:

```
<form onsubmit="check()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Your string:</label>
        <div contenteditable class="form-control h-50" id="string"></div>
        <div class="form-group text-center m-3">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Check</button>
        </div>
</form>
```

My JS code in index.view.php: (no JQuery, please)

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function check() {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("POST", "index.php", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { //result
        };

        var data = {
            "string": "hello"
        };
        xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
</script>
```

My index.php:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

if (!empty($data)) {
    $string = $data->string;
    echo $string;
}
```

Comment: What does _"returns empty"_ mean? What is "empty" in PHP?

Comment: @jabaa stream doesn't contain any data. No data is sent by Ajax request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never send the Ajax request.

---

When you click the submit button a submit event is triggered on the form.

The function you assign with the `onsubmit` attribute runs.

This sets up an Ajax request and *almost* sends it.

Then the function ends, and the form submission continues.

This makes a GET request to the current URL (because there is no `action` attribute) with an empty query string appended (because there are no successful form controls in the form).

The Ajax request is cancelled because the browser navigated away from the page.

---

If you want to use Ajax then you need to prevent the normal behaviour of the form submission.

First stop using the `onsubmit` event and move to the modern `addEventListener` function which was introduced in the late '90s. This makes it easier to manage event objects without having to explicitly pass them or use the deprecated global event object.

```
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', check);
```

Then accept the event object that will be passed as the first argument to your function and prevent the default behaviour.

```
function check(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // etc
}
```

---

Note that if you want to inspect the response other than through the Network tab of your browser's developer tools you will need to write JavaScript to do so.

Your `onreadystatechange` event handler doesn't do anything at the moment (and would probably be better off as `onload` anyway).